# Google maps in Joomla 3 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, joomla

I've been trying to develop a Joomla module, displaying a map with a single marker.
I have a javascript file that works fine in HTML, but I cannot get the Joomla implementation to work. 
After a lot of bughunting, my current code is:

default.php

```
<?php 
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die; ?>
<div id="map" style="width:200px;height:50px"></div>
<?php $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key]&signed_in=true&libraries=places');
    $document->addScript('/modules/mod_helloworld/maps.js');
    $document->addScriptDeclaration('window.onload(jQuery("map").googleMaps());')?>
<?php echo $hello; ?>
```

The API key is set in the live version, but omitted here for ease of reading.

helper.php

```
<?php
class modHelloWorldHelper
{
    public static function getHello( $params )
    {
        return 'Hello, World!';
    }
}
?>
```

mod_google_maps.php

```
<?php 
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php' );

$hello = modHelloWorldHelper::getHello($params);
require( JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_helloworld'));
?>
```

When I upload this module to my Joomla site and activate the module, it will display the "Hello, World!" on the sidepanel as it's supposed to (checking if the module works), but the map itself does not show up. 
The console returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
  Xi
  Jj
  $.fn.googleMaps
  (anonymous function)
```

$.fn.googleMaps is defined in the maps.js file using jQuery (in noConflict mode, using the jQuery descriptor. jQuery is only referred to as "$" in the console output)

I have checked that the name of the div is the correct one several times, and have set a height and width using pixels instead of percent. The div shows up, but is empty.

Test site is here: http://dev.xander.dk.web1.symatic.dk/

UPDATE: It turns out Joomla was serving a wrong maps.js file. It was serving the first version that was uploaded to the server, but the one it should be using has had some very important changes made to it, including the name of the div.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery("map")

shoud be

jQuery("#map")

EDIT

in the google jquery plugin your adding the map to

```
document.getElementById('map-canvas')
```

this need to point to

```
 document.getElementById('map')
```

or use context (this)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything.
And in HTML, it worked fine if you called it as jQuery("map").googleMaps();

Comment: jQuery("map") is looking for <map> jQuery("#map") is looking for id="map"

Comment: Turns out the problem was both what you wrote, but also that the script was running before the div was set.
I fixed it by using addscript with the defer attribute set to true, and executing the script from within the file. 

This works as it should.

Thanks for the help.